# Changing If Else statement to Loop in C++

Tags: c++

I'm very new to coding.
Is there a way to change this If else statement to a loop to sort the list of this books to ascending and descending order or the number of (books per subject).

Basically it emulates a library system where you choose a subject then you will see the unsorted books with  the quantity before the names of the books, and last you will choose how do you want to see the list either ascending or descending order list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int subject;
    cout<<"What subject? \n" ;
    cout<<"[1] English \n" ;
    cout<<"[2] Mathematics \n" ;
    cout<<"[3] Science \n" ;
    cout<<"[4] Filipino \n\n" ;
    cin>>subject;
    switch(subject) {
        case 1 : cout<<"How do you want to see the books on this subject? \n\n";
                 cout<<"3 Spelling\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Alphabet\n" ;
                 cout<<"6 Punctuations\n" ;
                 cout<<"2 Grammar\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Alphabet\n" ;
                 cout<<"1 Literature\n\n" ;
        {

        int a = 1;
        int ans;

        ans=a;

        int inp;
        cout<<"type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n \n"<<endl;
        cin>>inp;

        if (inp==ans) {
        cout<<"Ascending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Literature\n" ;
        cout<<"2 Grammar\n" ;
        cout<<"3 Spelling\n" ;
        cout<<"4 Short Stories\n" ;
        cout<<"5 Alphabet\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Punctuations\n" ;}
        else{
        cout<<"Descending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Punctuations \n" ;
        cout<<"5 Alphabet \n" ;
        cout<<"4 Short Stories \n" ;
        cout<<"3 Spelling \n" ;
        cout<<"2 Grammar\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Literature\n" ;
       
         } 
         } 
        break;
        case 2 : cout<<"How do you want to see the books on this subject? \n";
                 cout<<"3 Calculus\n" ;
                 cout<<"1 Algebra\n" ;
                 cout<<"6 Trigonometry\n" ;
                 cout<<"4 Graphs\n" ;
                 cout<<"2 Functiosn\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Geometry\n\n" ;
        {

        int a = 1;
        int ans;

        ans=a;

        int inp;
        cout<<"type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n \n"<<endl;
        cin>>inp;

        if (inp==ans) {
        cout<<"Ascending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Algebra\n" ;
        cout<<"2 Functiosn\n" ;
        cout<<"3 Calculus\n" ;
        cout<<"4 Graphs\n" ;
        cout<<"5 Geometry\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Trigonometry\n" ;}
        else{
        cout<<"Descending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Trigonometry \n" ;
        cout<<"5 Geometry \n" ;
        cout<<"4 Graphs \n" ;
        cout<<"3 Calculus \n" ;
        cout<<"2 Functions \n" ;
        cout<<"1 Algebra \n" ;
       
         } 
         }
        break;
        case 3 : cout<<"How do you want to see the books on this subject? \n";
                 cout<<"3 Solar system\n" ;
                 cout<<"1 Living things\n" ;
                 cout<<"6 Newton's Theory\n" ;
                 cout<<"4 Energy\n" ;
                 cout<<"2 Non-living things\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Elements\n\n" ;
        {

        int a = 1;
        int ans;

        ans=a;

        int inp;
        cout<<"type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n \n"<<endl;
        cin>>inp;

        if (inp==ans) {
        cout<<"Ascending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Living things\n" ;
        cout<<"2 Non-living things\n" ;
        cout<<"3 Solar system\n" ;
        cout<<"4 Energy\n" ;
        cout<<"5 Elements\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Newton's Theory\n" ;}
        else{
        cout<<"Descending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Newton's Theory\n" ;
        cout<<"5 Elements \n" ;
        cout<<"4 Energy \n" ;
        cout<<"3 Solar system \n" ;
        cout<<"2 Non-living things\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Living things\n" ;
       
         } 
         }
        break;
        case 4 : cout<<"How do you want to see the books on this subject? \n";
                 cout<<"3 Gramatika\n" ;
                 cout<<"1 Pandiwa\n" ;
                 cout<<"6 Tamang Pagbigkas\n" ;
                 cout<<"4 Bantas\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Mga kilalang manunulat\n" ;
                 cout<<"2 Maikling Kwento\n\n" ;
        {

        int a = 1;
        int ans;

        ans=a;

        int inp;
        cout<<"type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n \n"<<endl;
        cin>>inp;

        if (inp==ans) {
        cout<<"Ascending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Pandiwa\n" ;
        cout<<"2 Maikling Kwento\n" ;
        cout<<"3 Gramatika\n" ;
        cout<<"4 Bantas\n" ;
        cout<<"5 Mga kilalang manunulat\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Tamang Pagbigkas\n" ;}
        else{
        cout<<"Descending\n\n" ;
        cout<<"6 Tamang Pagbigkas \n" ;
        cout<<"5 Mga kilalang manunulat \n" ;
        cout<<"4 Bantas \n" ;
        cout<<"3 Gramatika \n" ;
        cout<<"2 Maikling kwento\n" ;
        cout<<"1 Pandiwa\n" ;
       
         } 
         }
        break; 
        default : cout<<"Choose between 1,2,3,and 4";
        }
    
}
```

Comment: You *really* need to learn about functions to tame this code. You should not be just having at it in `main()`.

Comment: First question: What list of books? I can't find any data structures here to sort, just a whole heap of `cout` chaff. I'm expecting to find, at least, `std::vector<std::string>`, or if you need an intrinsic index in there, too, consider `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`.

Comment: Please don't give us a menu system unless your question is about menu systems. For example, pick a subject for us, and get rid of the code for handling the other subjects. Make your code as simple as possible while demonstrating the error. *Do not attempt to show us a library system.* Given this question's textual part, I expect to see exactly **one** `if`-`else` statement in the *example* code, and very little around it.

Comment: @JaMiT sorry about that I will take note of this, anyways thanks to the responds I finally solve my problems.

Comment: @Newbies *"I will take note of this"* -- please do more than just taking note. Please improve your question. Keep in mind that the intended purpose of this site is to provide questions and answers **for the future**; solving the problem for a question's poster is "just" a nice side-effect. Help yourself by helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to improve a lot in your coding as well as in designing this application.
Firstly you want to convert your if else statement to loop, to do you can use the while loop and add one more option to user to exit from menu. All the menu (where you are asking user to enter choice) should have exit option. for example below

```
case 1 : cout<<"How do you want to see the books on this subject? \n\n";
                 cout<<"3 Spelling\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Alphabet\n" ;
                 cout<<"6 Punctuations\n" ;
                 cout<<"2 Grammar\n" ;
                 cout<<"5 Alphabet\n" ;
                 cout<<"1 Literature\n\n" ;
                 cout<<"0 Exit Menu/Application\n\n";
```

To rearrange your books by name you can compare the book's name first character ASCII value and rearrange the books in sorted order inside the loop as per Menu selection.

Hope this help you. I am not suggesting here to use a better data structure because keeping in mind you are new in coding.